# Как считывать нажатие UI кнопки в юнити2д?

Tags: c#, unity3d

При разработке игры на андроид я столкнулся с проблемой:
Мне нужно считать данные кнопки.
Использовать метод не получится, т.к при нажатии в переменной bool должно быть true, а если не нажата false (проблема выставить значение false).
Вот код:

```
    void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(joystick.Horizontal * playerSpeed, joystick.Vertical * playerSpeed);
}
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.tag == "Weapon")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < allWeapons.Length; i++)
        {
            if (collision.name == allWeapons[i].name)
            {
                unlocedWeapons.Add(allWeapons[i]);
                Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            }
        }
        SwichWeapon();
    }
}
public void SwichWeapon()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < unlocedWeapons.Count; i++)
    {
        if (unlocedWeapons[i].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            unlocedWeapons[i].SetActive(false);
            if(i != 0)
            {
                unlocedWeapons[i - 1].SetActive(true);                   
            }
            else
            {
                unlocedWeapons[unlocedWeapons.Count - 1].SetActive(true);
                weaponIcon.sprite = unlocedWeapons[unlocedWeapons.Count - 1].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
            }
            weaponIcon.SetNativeSize();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Какие данные тебе с этой кнопки надо считать? Что тебе нужно сделать? Конкретнее опиши

Comment: У меня есть функция getWeapon, и если игрок косается колизии с тегом "Weapon" она срабатывает. Так же есть кнопка которая отвечает за поднятие оружия, если использовать метод то я смогу установить значение true через метод , но не смогу установить значение false.

Comment: Для чего это значение true? Даже из пояснения ничего не понятно, прикладывай свой код. Жми править под вопросом и прикладывай.

Comment: Просто в похожих вопросах предлагали создать метод в котором будет изменяться спец. переменная bool на true (этот метод вызывался в onClick), но проблема в том как установить значение false, ведь если я нажму кнопку она останется зажатой. Просто вызвать метод отвечающий за подбор оружия не выйдет, т.к он вызывается в OnTriggerEnter2D и должен срабатывать только тогда, когда есть тег "Weapon", что без OnTriggerEnter2D сделать невозможно.

Comment: Какая цель то всего этого? Подобрать оружие при входе в триггер? Ты описываешь какие-то ненужные подробности, но не пишешь, чего хочешь добиться. Напиши, что ты хочешь сделать, а не то, как ты это делаешь

Comment: При входе в триггер и нажатии кнопки оружие поднимается, но как тебе помогут данные подробности ?

Comment: Это единственная нужная информация. Все остальное, что ты понаписал, абсолютно не несет в себе никакого смысла. Отдели инпут. Делай не проверки по тэгу, а проверки по компоненту. [Вот](https://hatebin.com/jscgqwsssz) грубый пример того, как это может выглядеть. При входе в триггер, подписываешь на ивент нажатия кнопки метод который нужен и он выполнится, если ты в триггере нажмешь кнопку действия. Напиши ты сразу что тебе нужно вместо того, как ты это делаешь и тебе не пришлось бы ждать 19 часов ответа.

Comment: В любом случае спасибо !